# Decoupled Drupal - Security: files structure

Tags: deployment, http-request

I am running a Drupal 8.9.2 site as a content repository accessed via an Angular 8 app. So there is one administrator who uses the Drupal interface to write content / upload files eccc.... and anonymous users view that content via the Angular app.

I have set up some views with REST Export display and have been able to pull the content in my Angular app running both backend and frontend on localhost, but when I deployed to the server problems have arisen...

all my calls fail or get canceled, this was the configuration on localhost: the Drupal website was in a folder in XAMPP/htdocs/example the views rest endpoints were like: http://localhost/example/web/api/content the Angular app was in a folder on the desktop and was served at http://localhost:4200/home
now I put all the files for both backend and frontend on the root folder on the server, I also have commented this line ErrorDocument 404 /index.php in the htaccess file found in the web folder so that non existent urls are managed by the Angular app.

So the question is: What is the correct files structure in order to have the frontend at example.com/home and my Drupal site at example.com/web/admin/eccc..... (if it is possible, otherwise please suggest a better option).

Comment: there's likely more than one way to configure Apache for this setup. I'd suggest something of a host-based approach where `drupal.example.com` hosts your Drupal instance & `angular.example.com` hosts your Angular instance then have your angular app with a config variable that specifies the hostname for the API to consume.

Comment: @ShawnConn is right, see [How to Configure Multiple Sites with Apache](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/configure-apache-virtual-hosts-ubuntu-18-04/)

Comment: Thank you guys, but before buying two third-level domains from my hosting provider I would like to find another way. I found this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UwCX9oPpfPI&t=56s and this source code https://bitbucket.org/spinspire/d8-react/src/master/  (it is in react but I think the idea is the same) where they put the app inside the web folder. I will try and let you know, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, the calls were failing due to a wrong version of PHP (you need 7.2 or higher).
As for the files structure I just put all the files in the root folder, both for Drupal and Angular, it works having my Drupal site in the web folder, I don't know for other configurations.